# pep8 - statistics for whole project

Tags: python, pep8, code-inspection, pycodestyle, pep8-checker

I am working on a Python project and I am using the PyPI pep8 checker.

Is there a simple way to get a pep8 rating for my project? Like a percentage (eg. 10 lines doesn't match pep8, out of 100 lines) or any number to rate it?

As far as I know pep8 / pycodestyle do not provide such functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/). It provides a rating and a very nice and descriptive report.
In addition, there are more verification checks and options than just PEP8.

Comment: Out of sportsmanship, would you consider giving an up vote to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the code editor you use (PyCharm in my case), look for "run code inspection". That will give you all the warnings regarding PEP8 violations in your code.

**EDIT:** You mention that you're using "PyPI pep8 checker." [On their github page](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) it states they use [pycodestyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle) to check the code, the main page explains how to get the statistics you asked for, and there's a more complete error list [here](https://pycodestyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes). However, you're still probably better off using an IDE...